# How to show WP admin edit page within template page/post?

Tags: posts, pages, wp-admin, page-template

So I am wanting to show the `wp-admin/post.php?post=999&action=edit`
Inside my custom template of the `single.php` and `page.php`.

So I understand that I can do it using an iFrame by basically get_the_ID() of the current page and passing the URL of `wp-admin/post.php?post=999&action=edit` in the `src` of the iframe...

for example:

```
<iframe seamless="seamless" scrolling="yes" src="<?= get_bloginfo(url); ?>/wp-admin/post.php?post=<?= get_the_ID(); ?>&amp;action=edit" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

However, I do not want to completely access the wp-admin from an iframe, causing a cycle of a "looking into mirror-to-mirror effect" with iframes-to-iframes.

I've also thought that if I used an Iframe, then I would have to write a jquery script to capture all `<a>` and turn them into an onclick function to send the link to the:

`window.top.location.href = url;`.

If there is a better way to access the edit page screen from the template, please let me know...

My goal is to make the wordpress admin completely show on frontend of site

Comment: Do you actually, *specifically*, want to include all of `wp-admin/post.php` in a page/post? Or do you really just want to be able to create posts from the front end? If it’s just the latter, then this would not be the right way to go about it.

Comment: You can create a post in PHP via `wp_insert_post`, or via the REST API in javascript ( that's how the block editor does it ). There are also security concerns

Comment: @JacobPeattie Yes! I want to specifically include wp-admin into a frontend. I don't want to create posts, just edit them.

Comment: @TomJNowell I've written a script using the Rest API to pull in posts... I just want to edit them from the frontend utilizing WP default admin features... The MAIN reason why I want to use the frontend is to use the permalink structure for pages: domain/parent/child/gchild/ggchild and don't want to use wp-admin/post.php?action=edit........etc

Comment: As far as security concerns.. If in an iframe the WP login screen would still show... if used without the iframe, I would have to wrap the content all in an `is_admin()` function.

Comment: This sounds utterly complicated, bloated and not very secure. Imho, I'd pull in the posts to the frontend, write some small ajax to update the database on save. Then you have your clean permalink structure, also there is a plugin "frontend-posts". Just sayin'.

Comment: Thanks @user3135691 But it won't be bloated.. See, I disable the theming scripts on the theme by allowing only WP functions to work on the theme. Right now I have an iframe at full width/height. If I type the page structured URL in the browser, based on returned ID, I will get the backend edit page via the iframe. Maybe I just need to remove the admin menu and that will work.... Just was wondering if anyone knew of a function. I know that ACF has a function for this.

Comment: This is an awful lot of effort just to change admin URLs. This is a huge, messy hack. Why is that so important?